# How do I combine 2D and 3D animation together?

Tags: animation, export, video

Would it be possible to use 3D animation using Blender and put it in a 2D software animation such as Adobe Flash professional?

Answer (score 1):

Combining video images with 3D generated imagery is possible as long as the video in question is encoded using a [format supported](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/files/video_formats.html?highlight=formats) by blender.

**Blender has no support for Flash** so the images would need to be transcoded first using a different program.

Likewise. Blender cannot export video on Flash format. You would need to render first on a video format (or image sequence) and encode into Flash with a different program.